# How to hide the footer view in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a xml layout with 7 edittext fields also I have added one footer view below the Edittext's. When I touch the edit text I want to hide the footer and once completed the text typing. I want to show the footer again to the user.Please any one help me in this

Added the code here

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/reg_ScrollRegDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/reg_RlTitleHeader" > 

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_LlPersonDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_RlPersonLastName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/reg_EtPersonLastName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" 
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_TvPersonLnameHint"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/reg_person_last_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_TvPersonLnameHintStar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reg_TvPersonLnameHint"
                    android:text="@string/asterisk"
                    android:textColor="@color/red" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_RlPersonFirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/reg_EtPersonFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_TvPersonFnameHint"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/reg_person_first_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_TvPersonFnameHintStar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reg_TvPersonFnameHint"
                    android:text="@string/asterisk"
                    android:textColor="@color/red" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlMemberName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_EtMemberName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />

            <requestFocus />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvMemberNameHint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_create_member_name"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvMemberNameStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reg_TvMemberNameHint"
                android:text="@string/asterisk"
                android:textColor="@color/red" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_EtPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlConfirmPwd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_EtConfirmPwd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvConfirmPwdHint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_confirm_password"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_EtEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" >
            </EditText>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlEmailcnfm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_EtEmailcnfm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" >
            </EditText>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlCountryZip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_RlCountry"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/reg_EtCountry"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_RlZip"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/reg_EtZip"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:maxLength="9"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>           

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_LlTeamDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_RlTeamName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/reg_EtTeamName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />                    
            </RelativeLayout>                 
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlFirstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_EtFirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvFirstNameHint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_ind_first_name"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvFirstNameHintStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/reg_TvFirstNameHint"
                android:text="@string/asterisk"
                android:textColor="@color/red" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlLastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_EtLastName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/et_text_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvLastNameHint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_ind_last_name"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvLastNameHintStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/reg_TvLastNameHint"
                android:text="@string/asterisk"
                android:textColor="@color/red" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_LlGender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvGender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/reg_gender"
                android:textColor="@color/et_bg_tv_fg_color"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvGenderStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/asterisk"
                android:textColor="@color/red" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_LlRbGender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:ems="5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                <CheckedTextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_CtvGenderFemale"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
                    android:checkMark="@drawable/reg_custom_radio_button"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/reg_gender_male"
                    android:textColor="@color/et_bg_tv_fg_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <CheckedTextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_CtvGenderMale"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:checkMark="@drawable/reg_custom_radio_button"
                    android:checked="true"
                     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/reg_gender_female"
                    android:textColor="@color/et_bg_tv_fg_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_RlYearOfBirth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvYearOfBirth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvYobHint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_year_of_birth"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reg_TvYobHintStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/reg_TvYobHint"
                android:text="@string/asterisk"
                android:textColor="@color/red" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reg_IvDropDownYob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_content_desc"
                android:src="@drawable/reg_drop_down_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_LlProfilePicContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_RlProfilePicHolder"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_TvProfilePicFiller"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/reg_portrait_pic"
                    android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_IvProfilePicPreview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_content_desc"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reg_LlBtnHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/reg_BtnBrowseGallery"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/reg_upload_btn"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/reg_BtnCamera"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reg_BtnBrowseGallery"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/reg_take_photo_btn" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_LlBioRoot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/profile_etBio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_reg_edit_text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="@string/profile_biohint"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="250"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_hint_et_border"
                android:textColorHint="@color/tv_hint_et_border"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_LlRegisterButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reg_BtnRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/reg_register_btn" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/reg_LlImagePreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Comment: your title is not suitable to your question...

Answer (score 1):

use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your Android Mainifest file and define in Activity tag.

```
<activity
    android:name="AddNewScheduleActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

For this you do not need to hide footer.The Keyboard is open over footer.

Comment: when keyboard is present the layout is not scrolling

Comment: Add your Linear/Realtive layout to ScrollView.